# Do we use weighted or unweighted data when doing categorical data analysis?

Tags: categorical-data, survey-weights

Im quite confuse if I should use a weighted or unweighted survey data when doing categorical data analysis such as Chi-square, G2, concordant or discordant analysis, etc.

Basically, these analyses use the numbers in a cross tab table. My take is to use  weighted data because its assumed its a better approximate of the population value. However, using the weighted (and expanded) data may influence the p-value making most of the results significant.

Any idea is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the survey and the meanings of the weights.  Could you explain?

Comment: It is a community survey and the survey weights estimates the number of people in a population.

Comment: You should use the weighted as this is a sampling issue not a test statistic issue